# User Cannot Enter Text, Index Out Of Bounds Exception

Tags: java, arraylist, javafx, textfield, indexoutofboundsexception

My code runs but when the user inputs text into the text field I am getting an Out Of Bounds Exception. I think it has something to do with this line of code where I give the empty box a value: `int express = (str != null && !"".equals(str)) ? Integer.parseInt(str) : -1;` but I am not sure. Is there a different way to do this? Here is the code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

public class Main extends Application {

   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) {


      ArrayList<Integer> deck;
      deck = new ArrayList<>();
      int i = 1;
      while(i < 52){
         deck.add(i);
         i++;
      }
      final AtomicReference<String> result = new AtomicReference<>("go.");

      Collections.shuffle(deck);

      BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();

      HBox top = new HBox(10);
      Label display = new Label(result.toString());
      Button btShuffle = new Button("Shuffle");

      top.getChildren().add(display);
      top.getChildren().add(btShuffle);


      HBox center = new HBox(10);
      Card card1 = new Card(deck.get(0));
      center.getChildren().add(card1);

      Card card2 = new Card(deck.get(1));
      center.getChildren().add(card2);

      Card card3 = new Card(deck.get(12));
      center.getChildren().add(card3);

      Card card4 = new Card(deck.get(14));
      center.getChildren().add(card4);



      btShuffle.setOnAction(
            e -> {
               Collections.shuffle(deck);
              center.getChildren().clear();    
              center.getChildren().add(new Card(deck.get(0)));
              center.getChildren().add(new Card(deck.get(1)));
              center.getChildren().add(new Card(deck.get(2)));
              center.getChildren().add(new Card(deck.get(3)));

            });





      HBox bottom = new HBox(10);
      Label expression = new Label("Please Enter the expression: ");

      TextField tfExpress = new TextField();
      LinkedList<Object> expInput = new LinkedList<>();
      ArrayList<Character> signs = new ArrayList<>();
      signs.add('/');
      signs.add('+');
      signs.add('(');
      signs.add(')');
      signs.add('-');
      signs.add('^');
      signs.add('*');
      signs.add('%');
      String str = tfExpress.getText();
      char tempStor[] = str.toCharArray();
      for(char c: tempStor){
         expInput.add(c);
      }

      int express = (str != null && !"".equals(str)) ? Integer.parseInt(str) : -1;      



      expInput.removeIf(p-> p.equals(signs));

      Button btVerify = new Button("Verify");
      bottom.getChildren().add(expression);
      bottom.getChildren().add(tfExpress);
      bottom.getChildren().add(btVerify);

      btVerify.setOnAction(
            (ActionEvent e) -> {
               if(card1.CardValue() == (int)expInput.get(0)
               && card2.CardValue() == (int)expInput.get(1)
               && card3.CardValue() == (int)expInput.get(2)
               && card4.CardValue() == (int)expInput.get(3)){
                  if(express == 24){
                     result.set("Correct");
                  }
                  else
                     result.set("Incorrect");

               }
               else
                  result.set("The numbers in the expression don't "
                     + "match the numbers in the set.");
            });

      pane.setTop(top);
      pane.setCenter(center);
      pane.setBottom(bottom);

      Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
      primaryStage.setTitle("24 card game");
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      primaryStage.show();
   }

   public class Card extends Pane {
      public int cardVal;
      Card(int card){
         Image cardImage;
         cardImage = new Image("card/"+ card +".png");
         getChildren().add(new ImageView(cardImage));
         cardVal = card;

      }

      public int CardValue(){
         int card = 0;

         if(cardVal <= 13){
            card = cardVal;
         }
         else if(cardVal > 13 && cardVal <= 26){
            card = cardVal - 13;
         }
         else if(cardVal > 26 && cardVal <= 39){
            card = cardVal - 26;
         }
         else if(cardVal > 39 && cardVal <= 52){
            card = cardVal - 39;
         }


         return card;
      }




   }



   public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
   }

}
```

And here is the Exception:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.LinkedList.checkElementIndex(LinkedList.java:555)
    at java.util.LinkedList.get(LinkedList.java:476)
    at Main.lambda$start$2(Main.java:109)
    at Main$$Lambda$74/1787879.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8216)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3724)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3452)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1728)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2461)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:348)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:273)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:382)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:553)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:925)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$38/2075313.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Are these typos:  `Card card3 = new Card(deck.get(12));` and `Card card4 = new Card(deck.get(14));` (I mean using indices `12` and `14`)?

Comment: Not exactly. I was just messing around with different indexes. Does it matter which ones I use? My shuffle button is working properly.

Comment: Okay, that wasn't causing problems because the deck has 52 items. All the magic numbers make the code a bit hard to follow..

Comment: Add a breakpoint on " char tempStor[] = str.toCharArray();" line, debug and check the content of the array. Also check if tfExpress.getText(); is returning an empty string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The failure is in

```
btVerify.setOnAction(
        (ActionEvent e) -> {
           if(card1.CardValue() == (int)expInput.get(0)
```

Some lines above you create a new LinkedList so there aren't any values in it. This leads to the exception.

Edit: As a reply to some comments. A possible solution could look like:
(without further necessary refactorings ;))

```
final 
btVerify.setOnAction(
    (ActionEvent e) -> {
            LinkedList<Character> expInput = new LinkedList<Character>();
            for(char c: tfExpress.getText().toCharArray()){
                expInput.add(c);
            }

            if(card1.CardValue() == Integer.valueOf(expInput.get(0))
                 && card2.CardValue() == Integer.valueOf(expInput.get(1) )
                 && card3.CardValue() == Integer.valueOf(expInput.get(2))
                 && card4.CardValue() == Integer.valueOf(expInput.get(3))){
                 if(express == 24){
                     result.set("Correct");
                 }
                 else
                    result.set("Incorrect");

             }
             else
                 result.set("The numbers in the expression don't "
                            + "match the numbers in the set.");
         });
```

Comment: Few lines below of the line you are mentioning there is this for(char c: tempStor){
         expInput.add(c);
      } So indeed the linkedlist isnt empty unless the tempStor[] is emtpty

Comment: Thats only partially correct, because the loop will never be executed. The chars from the tempStore are the characters from a newly created TextField which will probably contain zero characters..

Comment: My exceptions is saying that I have a size of 0 for the list right? So could I expand this some how? @LalitRao

Comment: Add something to the list. Everything I do atm is static code analysis. 
If I am correct the solution would something like:
Call the TextField directly in the lamda expression.

Comment: Thank you very much! My verify button no longer gives error. Now for some reason though my AtomiceReference will not change when I input values. Could this be because of where it is placed?

Comment: I didn't checked the whole code or run it. There are probably multiple errors in it. Check if you konw someone near you with programming experience who can give you some tipps and help you.